# Android: Display all images from a specific directory on the screen

Tags: android

I'm new to android and am trying to create an app that allows the user to take a picture which is then stored in external storage, im storing these pictures in a specific folder on the device and know how to display one specific picture from that folder but I don't know how to display a list of **all** the pictures.

Any help would be much appreciated as im really struggling with this and am finding it difficult to find out how to do it online.

Comment: I would recommended you go to this link. [displaying-images-from-sd-card-in-Gridview](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.in/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html) **Update:** try this [http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/10/gridview-example-load-images-to.html](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/10/gridview-example-load-images-to.html)

Comment: I tried that code already but I found it very difficult to modify it for a specific folder. Thanks

Comment: @GrahamKill then what you want do?

Comment: Have you implemented any code for this?

Comment: @M D What I want to do is load all the images residing in an external folder onto the screen. Just looked at the update there, it looks like  what I need, I will test it when I get some free time. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the data to a listadapter and display it using a gridview

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html